# Bootstrap table extending beyond the panel when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I am trying to build a panel with a table inside. The code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-12">

             <div class="panel">
               <div class="panel-heading bg-primary">
                <h3 class="panel-title">This is a panel</h3>
              </div>

              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?
                 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p.
              </div> <!-- panel body -->

                <!-- Table inside the panel -->
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Firstname</th>
                      <th>Lastname</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>John</td>
                      <td>Doe</td>
                      <td>john@example.com</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Mary</td>
                      <td>Moe</td>
                      <td>mary@example.com</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>July</td>
                      <td>Dooley</td>
                      <td>july@example.com</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div> <!-- panel -->


          </div> <!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
```

The panel looks o.k on most screen sizes, except the mobile one where the table breaks the panel. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since the example is very similar with the one found on the Bootstrap website and it seems to be responsive on all screen sizes.  Thank you!

[image: Table breaking the panel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the .table in `table-responsive`

Wrap the `panel` in `col-xs-12` and remove the col class from the panel itself (the panel will always span the full-width of its parent)

Include the `table` in your `panel-body`

I also noticed a `<p>` tag which wasn't closed in your `panel-body` :p

Hope this helps!

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-heading bg-primary">
            <h3 class="panel-title">This is a panel</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
              make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
              passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

            <!-- Table inside the panel -->
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>john@example.com</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Mary</td>
                    <td>Moe</td>
                    <td>mary@example.com</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>July</td>
                    <td>Dooley</td>
                    <td>july@example.com</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The table doesn't break out of the panel anymore but it still has that horizontal scroll bar at the bottom. I know this is the normal behavior when the window browser is too small so I was wondering if there's any solution to make the whole table display even on small screen sizes, without having to scroll left/ right. Thank you!

Comment: Not really Casia :( that's just how things are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.table-responsive` class for parent div?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
   ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried <div class="table table-responsive" and nothing changes (using class="table-responsive" makes the table look very weird).

Comment: Try div with table-responsive only. <div class="table-responsive"> as you can see in my answer.

Comment: No, it's not working. The solution makes the table even bigger and gives me a scroll bar at the bottom of the page.